# Detect whether Web application is running for the first time

Tags: java

I am developing a web application to migrate images from CVS to Adobe CQ. There is a requirement to maintain versioning for the images in a database table. The flow is as follows:

1. Check Out files from CVS -- returns a list of all files checked out, but does not tell whether a file was updated or newly added to CVS! (Due to the files being binary file, it seems it is not able to detect updates and all files are treated as additions)
2. Check if this is application's first run, if yes, then treat all files as additions. If not, for every file, check database for presence of record corresponding to this file. If record present, treat as update, else insert

... Carry on with other operations

3. For every insert, add an entry in the database

I have to detect if the application is running for the first time, or has been run previously. This also needs to support future tasks such as resetting everything and starting the application from scratch.

What would be a good way to do this? The application is hosted in WebSphere in Linux. I have thought of two ways:

a. creating an entry in a file with a flag set to true, which I will have to reset to false after the first run - difficult for a user to reset later

b. creating a `.firstrun` or similar file in the app folder somewhere and check presence of this file to determine first run, easier to reset for any user

Which of this is a better way? Or is there any other way to do it better?

Comment: Why not check the database to see if there is an entry for the image already? Are there other sources for the database table?

Comment: Yes, I am doing that in step 2. But in the first run of the application I know that there are going to be no entries, so I don't want to keep checking the database for every image. The number of images can be very high, in the order of tens of thousands.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned database. Why not to store in db, in even more extended way: when what version, # of runs, etc.

Comment: Version and timestamp is present in database. As I mentioned in my comment above, for the first run I already know that there are going to be no entries in the database. therefore I do not want to check the database for every image. And hence the need to detect first run of the application